# Inside for loop if condition not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, if-statement, foreach

I am trying to get Data from database to text box on select index changed.  I am getting an output, but I'm using simple if statement inside my loop but its not working where am I doing wrong Please help me ??

Let me explain. I use two text box `txtEmployeeNumber` and `txtEmployeename` on `txtEmployeeNumber_TextChanged` I have written my logic code in that way that when `txtEmployeeNumber_TextChanged` fire then `txtEmployeename`  should fill its respective data and if `txtEmployeeNumber`  text not matching with any of data then should through an error No Data Found. But in both condition I am getting same error message

```
protected void txtEmployeeNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string EmployeeNo = "";
    string EmployeeName = "";
    int Row = 0;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdRegister.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            EmployeeNo = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("txtEmployeeNumber") as TextBox).Text;
        }
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)Application["Employee_details"];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[i]["Employee_ID"].ToString() == EmployeeNo)
            {
                (row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtEmployeeName") as TextBox).Text = dt.Rows[i]["Employee_Name"].ToString();
                EmployeeName = (row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtEmployeeName") as TextBox).Text;
                break;
            }
            else if ((row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtEmployeeName") as TextBox).Text == "")
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Error", "alert('No Data Found...')", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are three if's here which if is not working?

Comment: If statement will pass only when your condition is true. If you see only one output in any situation it means your first condition is not met, which means `dt.Rows[i]["Employee_ID"].ToString()` is not equal to `EmployeeNo`.

Comment: else if ((row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtEmployeeName") as TextBox).Text == "") this if block firing always if my condition is true or false in both situation its fairing

Comment: After getting error message i am getting my data from database

Comment: @MasLoo its dt.Rows[i]["Employee_ID"].ToString() working its filtering my data table data to matching employeenumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things go wrong, first of all you browse through all rows in the grid while only one textbox has changed. So for every Employeenumber in every row that is not in the datatable you get an errormessage already.

You can find the active/currentrow with: (sender as TextBox).NamingContainer as GridViewRow.

Second, for each record in the datatable before (if) you find the employeenumber you get an errormessage when the textbox is empty.

The code below should do what you want.

```
protected void txtEmployeeNumber_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string EmployeeNo = "";
    string EmployeeName = "";

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Application["Employee_details"];
    var row = (sender as TextBox).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    EmployeeNo = (row.FindControl("txtEmployeeNumber") as TextBox).Text;
    var txtEmployeeName = (row.FindControl("txtEmployeeName") as TextBox);
    EmployeeName = txtEmployeeName.Text;

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
        if (dt.Rows[i]["Employee_ID"].ToString() == EmployeeNo) {
            txtEmployeeName.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Employee_Name"].ToString();
            return;
        }
    }
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Error", "alert('No Data Found...')", true);
}
```

Comment: Amazing getting output as expected great explanation too understand logic